# Git checkout <latest branch you were working on> command

Tags: git

Is there a command to permit checkout the last branch? Like:

`git checkout --recent`

or

`git checkout --previous`

The idea is when you switch branch too often you it's easy to forget the branch you were working before the current one. Also if there's a way to set a alias for this that would be valide.

Comment: `git help reflog` to see how to examine the history of commits/branches you have been on; `git help rev-parse` for the various syntaxes (syntaxen?) for specifying what you want to check out...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to git checkout previous branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206801/is-there-any-way-to-git-checkout-previous-branch)

Comment: yes, it's the same idea of the selected answer here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is `-`

```
git checkout -
```

For example, say you're on branch `foo`, and there exists a branch `bar`.

```
* foo
bar
```

Check out `bar`

```
> git checkout bar

foo
* bar
```

Going back to `foo`

```
> git checkout -

* foo
bar
```

The `-` "shortcut" also works for the `cd` and `ls` commands from within a bash terminal.

Comment: I didn't know you could do this but I tried it and it works, +1

Comment: I believe this works in most bash shells. I've used `cd -` many times to go back to the directory I just came from. Saves a *ton* of hefty keystrokes.

Comment: @DesertIvy, so this is a system functionality or something provided by git? Would be nice to learn how this works too.

Comment: @Medeiros git may have implemented it this way to match the already existing functionality in the 'regular' bash shell

Comment: They way I understand it, it's a standard bash parameter that is used to indicate "last directory," and git-bash extended this to mean "last branch." It could have a more broad, overarching meaning that I'm missing, but that's my understanding of it. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8045499/464188) explains some of its other uses and quirks.

Comment: The question is, does this work in every system or is this system dependent?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's platform-independent. I've used this command in bash shells on my Windows work computer, my old *nix boxes, and my current Mac at home. You won't have any luck running it in a native Windows Command Prompt, so it sounds like for the most part it's bash-only.