# The contents of `__FILE__` when code is coming from STDIN

Tags: ruby, global-variables, stdin

If I run code like this, I get `-` in the `__FILE__` var:

```
cat script.rb | ruby
```

I can't find that documented anywhere though ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-__FILE__)). Where can I get exact details about it?

Comment: What is `__FILE__` when you run it like this: `ruby script.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

`-` is sometimes used to refer to `STDIN`.  This is a unix thing, and not unique to ruby.

Described a little bit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045479/whats-the-magic-of-a-dash-in-command-line-parameters)