# Extract from tar file to different directory in Bash

Tags: bash, unix, tar

I'm new to Bash and trying to unzip a tarball. Code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar="/cdrom/java/jre1-8u181-x64tar.gz"

# Unpack tarball
gunzip < $tar | tar xf -
```

This extracts the archive in current directory. How can I specify a location?

Using Solaris 10, Bash 3.2.51

Comment: Edited the title and tags. You are already successfully decompressing a file to get an archive; your question is about extracting the contents of the archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works pretty well everywhere - including Solaris, and as you only change directory in a sub-shell, it doesn't affect your location in the current session:

```
gunzip < $tar | ( cd /some/where/else && tar xf -)
```

Answer (score 3):

To extract the file to a specific directory

```
gunzip < $tar | tar -xf - --directory /path/to/extract/to
```

or

```
gunzip < $tar | tar -xf - -C /path/to/extract/to
```

Comment: `gunzip < $tar | tar -xf - -C /root/Documents/test` returns the error: `tar: 2 file(s) not extracted` on Solaris 10

Comment: are you running as root ?only `root` will have permission to write files to `/root/Documents/test`

Comment: yes running as root - the issue is with Solaris OS. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The `-xf` part of tar means to extract into the "f" file. try changing the `tar` command to something like

**Edit**

```
...| tar -xf - -C /path/to/your/desired/result/folder
```

sorry, @pitseeker is correct.  The `-C` option tells tar to change directory then do the extract

Comment: That seems not right. Following the "f" is the tar-file that is supposed to be extracted.

Comment: `...| tar -xf /root/Documents/test` returns the error: `tar: directory checksum error` on Solaris 10

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote your command is unpacking in the current directory:

```
gunzip < $tar | tar xf -
```

Add the "-C" option to give it an alternate target directory:

```
gunzip < $tar | tar xf - -C /another/target/directory
```

Note that the Solaris tar does not understand the `--directory` option.
See the [Solaris tar manpage](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/tar-1.html).

Just for the sake of completeness if you have Gnu-Tar (which is available for Solaris too) you can use this simpler command (which unzips and unpacks in one go):

```
tar xzf $tar -C /another/target/directory
```

On a side note: 
many people use a leading dash for the tar command parameters. That is redundant.
See the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045479) if you are interested.

Comment: `gunzip < $tar | tar xf - -C /another/target/directory` returns the error: `tar: 2 file(s) not extracted` on Solaris 10