# In this bash script, what does "-" mean? And how could one find out what it means?

Tags: node.js, bash, dockerfile, yargs

Here's the script:

```
node /app/ganache-core.docker.cli.js — quiet \ — account=”0x873c254263b17925b686f971d7724267710895f1585bb0533db8e693a2af32ff,100000000000000000000" \ — account=”0x8c0ba8fece2e596a9acfc56c6c1bf57b6892df2cf136256dfcb49f6188d67940,100000000000000000000"
```

I've read [What's the magic of "-" (a dash) in command-line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045479/whats-the-magic-of-a-dash-in-command-line-parameters).  And I took away that it CAN mean standard input... if the authors of the bash program define it as such.
However, [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/blob/61ba4e37542718fa099784d16bbe3658cf766442/cli.js) (link to ganache-core.docker.cli.js github file), I cannot find how or where the author of ganache-core.docker.cli.js would have defined the dash ("-") as standard input.  Can someone point that out as well?

Edit: I am looking for confirmation that the dashes do mean standard input for cli args, but more-so looking to understand, WHY they should be definitively be interpreted as stnin when according the linked question above it's only a convention.

Edit2: I suspect the CLI arg parsing library is [yArgs](https://github.com/yargs/yargs)

Comment: Is this really what your command line looks like?  The dashes here seem to be emdashes, quotes aren't quotes they're "smart" quotes, there's extra spaces.  I really doubt that's what your command line looks like.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `bash`; like any argument, it's up to the program receiving it to define what it means.

Comment: And, the em dashes are probably the result of something like MarkDown replacing `--` with an em dash.

Comment: @chepner in my question I'm asking where that is defined in the linked source

Comment: It probably isn't. If the script is using a library to parse the arguments, the logic for interpreting any conventional arguments like `-` or `--` would be defined there.

Comment: @Brad It does... https://medium.com/@lzhou1110/the-complete-truffle-suite-on-docker-truffle-ganache-drizzle-47ab18b1ec83

Comment: @chepner As I stated in the body of my question, I KNOW it's up the program to define what it means... I was looking for where the definition is in the linked source

 And this might be the library... https://github.com/yargs/yargs

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name I assure you, this is just a poorly formatted blog article.

Comment: @Brad that's not right.  I ran the script and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command line is just badly formatted.  You're reading into something that isn't there.  Some Blog software author thought it was a smart idea to auto-reformat the article so that hyphens and such were long dashes and quotes were "smart", etc.  In the end, somehow a space ended up after the dash, before the next parameter.

For example, let's look at this:

```
node /app/ganache-core.docker.cli.js — quiet
```

Even if we assume that's a regular hyphen `-`, we know it's not supposed to have a space after it.  It's supposed to be `-quiet`.  And, if you have any doubt about this, you can [read in the source code where this is defined](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/blob/61ba4e37542718fa099784d16bbe3658cf766442/args.js#L214):

```
.option('q', {
  group: 'Other:',
  alias: 'quiet',
  describe: 'Run ganache quietly (no logs)',
  type: 'boolean',
  default: false
})
```

The same is true for `-account`.

> And I took away that it CAN mean standard input... if the authors of the bash program define it as such.

Yes, that's correct.  I don't know what this software does, but if it's reading from STDIN, it's not because you told it to on the command line.  It's because that's what it does.

Comment: I also suspected that it meant "-quiet" , not, "- quiet".  But alas, with a normal dash (not the shift-dash) the script evaluates properly.  If you question the validity of what I'm saying I encourage you to see for yourself in a bash+node sandbox with "npm install ganache-cli" as a dependency

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name I'm sure it does run for you... that's irrelevant.  I'm sure it's just getting ignored.

Comment: Alright.  I'll consider further what you're suggesting

Comment: Absolutely correct.  double dash gets auto converted to long dash on many blogging platforms