# Understanding a script which uses ffmpeg to send rtmp input to node.js script

Tags: node.js, bash, ffmpeg, rtmp, live-streaming

I was trying to understand [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ivs-auto-captions-web-demo/blob/main/serverless/transcribe-server/run.sh) shell script which uses ffmpeg to take an rtmp input stream and send it to a node.js script. But I am having trouble understanding the syntax. What is going on here?

The script:

```bash
while :
do
  echo "Loop start"

  feed_time=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=start_time -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $RTMP_INPUT)
  printf "feed_time value: ${feed_time}"

  if [ ! -z "${feed_time}" ]
  then
  ffmpeg -i $RTMP_INPUT -tune zerolatency -muxdelay 0 -af "afftdn=nf=-20, highpass=f=200, lowpass=f=3000" -vn -sn -dn -f wav -ar 16000 -ac 1 - 2>/dev/null | node src/transcribe.js $feed_time

  else
  echo "FFprobe returned null as a feed time."
  
  fi

  echo "Loop finish"
  sleep 3
done
```

- What is `feed_time` here? What does it represent?
- What is this portion doing `- 2>/dev/null | node src/transcribe.js $feed_time`?
- What is the use of `sleep 3`? Does this mean that we are sending audio stream to node.js in chuncks of 3 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `feed_time` variable represents standard output of `ffprobe` command. This value needs to be passed to `node` script.
- `-` character doesn't have special meaning in *bash*, i.e. it is interpreted by `ffmpeg` command itself (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8045479/14967413)). According to `ffmpeg` [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Advanced-options):

> A - character before the stream identifier creates a "negative"
> mapping. It disables matching streams from already created mappings.

- `2>/dev/null` is a redirection that sends standard error output of `ffmpeg` command to `/dev/null` device, thus effectively discarding the error output (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563563/493568)). It is done because you want only the standard output (not error output) to be passed to `node` script.
- `|` is a pipe. It sends standard output of `ffmpeg` command to standard input of `node` script.
- `sleep` just delays execution of a script.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, what is the use of an infinite loop here? Is it to wait until ffprob gives a non-null output?

Comment: @ArpitShukla The loop continues even if `ffrop` gives non-null output. It is just repeating the work infinitely.

Comment: So, doesn't ffmpeg block until the stream has ended? Or does it transmit only a small chunk of stream data in single iteration and so to keep on transmitting data to node.js we need need an infinite loop?

Comment: @ArpitShukla `ffmpeg` reads file from `$RTMP_INPUT` (file or URL) and blocks until `ffmpeg` and `node` script process it, then waits 3 seconds. Apparently after that time data stored under `$RTMP_INPUT` may change, so the process starts again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the entire explanation.