# linux shell CLI file get mime-type from a string variable

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface, mime-types, file-type

I would like to detect an appropriate file extension in `sh` shell based on a content of a string variable.
I tried to use for that `file` - [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html)

If I do:

```bash
echo "bar" > foo.txt
file foo.txt
file --mime-type foo.txt
```

then I get a valid result:

```
foo.txt: ASCII text
foo.txt: text/plain
```

but how to get the same result without creating a file and get content type?

I tried:

```bash
file <(echo 'bar')
```

and got:

```
/dev/fd/63: symbolic link to pipe:[1452271]
```

and with:

```bash
echo 'bar' | file
```

I got:

```
Usage: file [-bcCdEhikLlNnprsSvzZ0] [--apple] [--extension] [--mime-encoding]
            [--mime-type] [-e <testname>] [-F <separator>]  [-f <namefile>]
            [-m <magicfiles>] [-P <parameter=value>] [--exclude-quiet]
            <file> ...
       file -C [-m <magicfiles>]
       file [--help]
```

Is there any way to get with `file`:

```
foo.txt: ASCII text
foo.txt: text/plain
```

but without creating the file itself?

Perhaps I could use other app instead of `file`?

Comment: What's the point? If you are creating the content of the file you know what it is, right?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Not in my case. The example I provided was simplified. I actually have to deal with an unknown type content that is stored in a variable. Detecting content type paves the way to save that content with a proper file extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use dash "-" argument of `file`.

Example 1:

```
file - <<< abc
/dev/stdin: ASCII text
```

Example 2:

```
echo abc | file - 
/dev/stdin: ASCII text
```

Example 3:

```
file - <<< '#!/bin/sh'
/dev/stdin: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Example 4:

```
MY_VAR='#!/bin/awk'
file --mime-type - <<< $MY_VAR
/dev/stdin: text/x-awk
```

Comment: Thank you for providing so many working examples. Would you comment on use of `-`. What it is and why you used it?

Comment: It depends on command. 
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045479/whats-the-magic-of-a-dash-in-command-line-parameters

Comment: In the `file` command, dash is used instead of a file name, for asking to read from stdin instead of a regular file.